# Check of row existed previous month (comparing data between two months) where number = certain value

Tags: php, mysql

ogi table

```
number    name         price         month         year
152       cheese       25            10            12
153       yogurt       12            10            12
152       cheese       22            11            12
153       yogurt       15            11            12
154       apples       30            11            12
```

I currently have the following query which is comparing rows between two months.

```
select a.price as p1, b.price as p2, a.distributor, a.number, a.name, (a.price - b.price) as pdiff from ogi a, ogi b where a.number = b.number and a.month = '" . $from_date . "' and b.month = '" . $to_date . "' and a.distributor = '" . $distributor . "'
```

I am now trying to check to see if a row did NOT exist in the previous month, to echo "did not exist" or something along those lines.

So, how can I **check to see if a row did not exist the previous month for number 154** (*found in the table above*) and echo "did not exist"?

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need to check the price delta of every month with the previous month, I would write your query this way:

```
SELECT
  a.*,
  b.price,
  case when b.number is not null
            then a.price-b.price
            else 'did not exist' end as priceDiff
FROM
  ogi a left join ogi b
  on a.number=b.number
     and b.year  = case when a.month=1
                             then a.year-1
                             else a.year end
     and b.month = case when a.month=1
                             then 12
                             else a.month-1 end
ORDER BY
  a.number, a.month
```

this will compare every price of every item with the price of the previous month, and will return 'did not exist' if there's no row for the previus month.

Please see [this fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/6ad55/6).

**EDIT:** I updated my answer, I think you are looking for this:

```
SELECT
  names.number,
  names.name,
  a.price pricea,
  b.price priceb,
  case when a.number is null then 'does not exist'
       when b.number is null then 'did not exist'
       else a.price-b.price end as priceDiff
FROM
  (select distinct number, name
   from ogi
   where (year=12 and month=11) or
         (year=12 and month=10)) names
   left join ogi a on names.number=a.number and a.month=11 and a.year=12
   left join ogi b on names.number=b.number and b.month=10 and b.year=12
ORDER BY
  a.number, a.month
```

Please notice that I am not considering the year, but if needed I can update the query.

Comment: Great! How would I only display the data that did not exist previously? This is a search filter so I only want to display "did not exist" - all other data should be excluded.

Comment: @Alex you could add this where condition `
WHERE b.number IS NULL` before `ORDER BY`. But notice that this will return all rows that have no previous month (number 154 - month 11, but also number 152,153 - month 10)

Comment: The URL looks like `page.php?from_month=11&to_month=12`. Would I be able to just set an if condition where a.month = $from_month and b.month = $to_month ?

Comment: Nevermind, I just have a.month set to $from_month and it works perfect now. Thanks!

Comment: Is there a way to modify the code to check if a.number is null instead? I tried switching case b.number and where b.number to a.number but no luck.

Comment: @Alex you need to check, for example, current month=12 and previous=11? and do you want to display "does not exist"?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by checking. I would want to echo "new item" if a.number is null

Comment: @Alex please see my updated answer, I edited and added one possible solution

Comment: This is perfect! You've seriously helped me a lot, thank you so much. Last question and then I will leave you alone (haha)...how would I take the year into account as well for the query? Thanks again.

Comment: @Alex i can update my answer to take into account the year as well, but you only have `from_month` and `to_month`, do you want to consider only the current year? If from_month=1 and to_month=2 I can only return rows of 2013, if from_month=12 and to_month=2 I can return from_month from the previus year, and to_month in the current year... is this correct?

Comment: Correct. I can create another form input/variable to hold the year so that the user chooses what year they are comparing to as well. So a user could compare data from 12/12 to 1/13

Comment: @Alex i updated my answer, if you can add two input variables to hold the years you could use this, but if you want to add just one input variable... I'll edit my answer later :)

Comment: Perfect! The updated code is exactly what needs to be done. Thanks again for all your help!

Answer (score 0):

Use a `LEFT JOIN`:

```
SELECT a.price AS p1, b.price AS p2, a.distributor, a.number, IFNULL(a.name, 'Does not exist') AS name, (a.price - IFNULL(b.price, 0)) AS pdiff
FROM ogi a
LEFT JOIN ogi b ON b.number = a.number
WHERE a.month = '$from_date' AND b.month = '$to_date' AND a.distributor = '$distributor'
```

I would highly advise you to change the table structure to make it normalized.

Answer (score 0):

I believe what you're looking for is an inner select.  The following pseudo query illustrates how you would grab any data that did not exist before the current month

```
SELECT * 
FROM table 
WHERE id NOT IN 
    (
        SELECT id 
        FROM table 
        WHERE created < var_containing_first_of_current_month
    )
```